# Is it possible to access SD card images or directories from python raspberry pi/ ubuntu

Tags: android, raspberry-pi

I'm populating my SD card with photos and I want to access this photo by raspberry pi's python where my mobile device is connected to respberry pi.

Comment: Hi @manun, as a rule of thumb, you should always provide [**_"Research Effort"_**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) before [asking in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I'm 100% sure what you want is possible given raspberry pi runs an standar linux and that you can access files from android in linux, and that you can open files/photos in python. So, probably your problem is more specific like "how to programatically mount an android", and probably you already tried something, just show it.